# Error while compiling a DLL - error LNK2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, lnk2005

I'd like to compile a DLL and I've got this error when I include `<afxdb.h>`:

```
error LNK2005: DllMain already defined in xlFunctions.obj
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I do have a `DllMain` function in my `xlfunctions.cpp` this is the entry point of my DLL.

The `Use of MFC property` is set to `Use MFC in a Shared DLL`

How can I solve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: what is the other object DllMain is defined in (look in the output window) - did you search google and check this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652

Comment: The other object is `dllmodul.obj`. I also tried to include `<Afx.h>` in all my source files but it didn't work.

Comment: did you actually read the link I posted? does it apply to your problem? Also, read this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148791

Comment: Yes I read it, That's where I found the include afx.h thing. I also tried to make my own Forcelib.h still doesn't work. I'm looking at your second kink.

Comment: do you have _USRDLL preprocessor definition?